# bradford persistent agent login not coming up

Tags: login, persistent

Wired connection. Desktop. It downloads and installs fine but at the point where the login is supposed to pop up. Nothing happens. Bradford says I have normal network access and it never shows it scanning. It just installs and does nothing. I have all of the updates and everything Bradford needs. And I've used the internet at this dorm before witb this computer. Tried reinstalling.disabling my firewall. Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, it is definitely a firewall problem. MAKE SURE! that your firewall is completely off/uninstalled.  Also, right click my computer and go to manage then services then find bradford and restart the service.

Finally spyware can be conflicting ( I have seen it countless times!)

Hopes this help